# Spring-boot ConditionalOnProperty with map-based properties

Tags: spring-boot

My spring-boot yaml properties look like this:

```
service:
    mycomponent:
        foo: 
            url: http://foo
        bar:
            url: http://bar
```

This results in the following properties being set in the Spring environment:

```
service.mycomponent.foo.url: http://foo
service.mycomponent.bar.url: http://bar
```

I'd like to define a 'mycomponent' bean if there are any properties that match `service.mycomponent.[a-z]*.url`. Is this possible using `@ConditionalOnExpression` or some other type of `@Conditional`?

I realize I can work around this by either adding a property such as `service.mycomponent.enabled: true` that could be used with `@ConditionalOnProperty` but I'd rather avoid that if possible.

Answer (score 4):

Here's the solution I ended up taking:

Create a custom `Condition` which searches for any properties with a certain prefix. The `RelaxedPropertyResolver` has the convenient `getSubProperties()` method. Alternative options I found were cumbersome to iterate through the `PropertySource` instances.

```
public class MyComponentCondition extends SpringBootCondition {
    @Override
    public ConditionOutcome getMatchOutcome(final ConditionContext context,
                                            final AnnotatedTypeMetadata metadata) {
        final RelaxedPropertyResolver resolver = new RelaxedPropertyResolver(context.getEnvironment());
        final Map<String, Object> properties = resolver.getSubProperties("service.mycomponent.");
        return new ConditionOutcome(!properties.isEmpty(), "My Component");
    }
}
```

Use that condition when setting up the bean:

```
@Conditional(MyComponentCondition.class)
@Bean
public MyComponent myComponent() {
    return new MyComponent();
}
```

I'm still curious if the same thing could be done with `@ConditionalOnExpression` directly.

Comment: Yes, @ConditionalOnExpression("!'${service.mycomponent}'.isEmpty()") works